# Channel model: LOS Component and Rician K-factor

Tags: digital-communications, fading-channel, mimo

I am asking about Rician K- Factor in this model:

[image: http://web.stanford.edu/group/introstwc/Course%20Notes/lect3.pdf]

I know that if $K=0$  then it is a pure Rayleigh fading, if $K= \infty$, then non fading Channel.

**What is it, if $0<K<\infty$ ?**

If i represet the NLOS component using the Kronecker model and take expected value from $\mathbf{H}$, then I get only loscomponent. **Will be it right**?

Comment: For $0 < K < \infty$, the channel is a combination of both a deterministic component (i.e., LOS) and a fading component. 

As the $K$-factor is the ratio of the energy in the deterministic Line-of-Sight (LOS) component to the energy in the aggregation of the random scattered paths (i.e., the fading component), higher $K$ means that the channel is more deterministic.

As for the 2nd part of your question, I'm not sure to understand what you meant.

Comment: @anpar That is an answer, not a comment!

Comment: OK, let me post that then.

Answer (score 1):

For $0 < K < \infty$, the channel is a combination of both a deterministic component (i.e., LOS) and a fading component.

As the $K$-factor is the ratio of the energy in the deterministic Line-of-Sight (LOS) component to the energy in the aggregation of the random scattered paths (i.e., the fading component), higher  means that the channel is more deterministic.

Comment: thanks. the second question: If i represet the NLOS component using the Kronecker model and take expected value from H, Did i get then  only LOS-component?